# Start and end columns in folder structure

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, document-library, column, folder

I need two columns in my folder structure with contracts where I can type start date and end date. I have tried: "+Add column" --> "Date and time". The result is that it applies to all folders, not only the present folder. I could live with that but it is also only possible to add the date for files, which I do not need. I need to add it for folders.

It used to work in another SharePoint, so I know it is possible.

Anyone who know what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a default behavior in SharePoint for folder content type.

If you want to add column values (metadata) for folders, you have below options:

1. Use **Edit in grid view** (quick edit) option
2. Custom Content Type inheriting from SharePoint default "Folder" content type
3. Use Document Sets instead of normal folders in library

You can find more information related to this at: [Different ways to tag folders with metadata in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/4-ways-to-tag-folders-with-metadata-in-sharepoint/)